# i have a issue in body package pl/sql when I select

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I currently have a procedure stored inside a package. I want to get all the data from the client table but I have an error. the problem is in procedure stored p_listar_cliente.

the code is:

create tables and insert

```
create table cliente (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR(50), address VARCHAR(50), salary NUMBER);

INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (1, 'camilo chaparro', 'popayan', 563321);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (2, 'ernesto lopez', 'ibague', 768954);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (3, 'camila españa', 'medellin', 113456);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (4, 'john jimenez', 'pasta', 789456);
INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (5, 'silvio jimenez', 'cali', 456123);
```

create package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE paquete_cliente_listar IS
--add clientes
  PROCEDURE p_agregar_clientes (
                                    c_id IN cliente.id%TYPE,
                                    c_name IN cliente.name%TYPE,
                                    c_address IN cliente.address%TYPE,
                                    c_salary IN cliente.salary%TYPE
                                    );

--delete clientes
  PROCEDURE p_quitar_clientes (c_id IN cliente.id%TYPE);

--Lists all customers 
   PROCEDURE p_listar_cliente;

--listar todos los clientes
END paquete_cliente_listar;
```

body package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY paquete_cliente_listar AS 
--agregar clientes
  PROCEDURE p_agregar_clientes (
                                    c_id  cliente.id%TYPE,
                                    c_name  cliente.name%TYPE,
                                    c_address  cliente.address%TYPE,
                                    c_salary cliente.salary%TYPE
                                    ) IS
    BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO cliente (id, name, address, salary) VALUES (c_id, c_name, c_address, c_salary);

    END p_agregar_clientes;

--quitar clientes
  PROCEDURE p_quitar_clientes (c_id IN cliente.id%TYPE) IS

  BEGIN 

    DELETE FROM cliente WHERE id = c_id;


  END p_quitar_clientes;

--listar todos los clientes

 PROCEDURE p_listar_cliente AS
    BEGIN

    clientes_cursor cliente%rowtype;

     CURSOR clientes_cursor IS 
        SELECT id, name, address, salary FROM cliente;




    OPEN clientes_cursor;
    LOOP
      FETCH clientes_cursor INTO clientes_cursor;
      EXIT WHEN clientes_cursor%notfound;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(clientes_cursor.id || ' ' || clientes.name);
     END LOOP;

 END p_listar_cliente;


END paquete_cliente_listar;
```

I have this issue:

Errors: PACKAGE BODY PAQUETE_CLIENTE_LISTAR
Line/Col: 30/21 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CLIENTE" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CLIENTE" to continue.

Line/Col: 32/13 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CLIENTES_CURSOR" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: PLS-00103 is a syntax error. Syntax errors are usually easy to resolve by comparing our code to [the examples in the PL/SQL Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-855AA11F-32CB-4CAD-9255-BE92A6821487).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that variables must be declared before the `BEGIN`.  But instead of trying to figure out how the variables work, your code will be simpler and faster if you use a cursor for loop, like this:

```
...
 PROCEDURE p_listar_cliente AS

 BEGIN

    FOR clientes IN
    (
      SELECT id, name, address, salary FROM cliente
    ) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(clientes.id || ' ' || clientes.name);
    END LOOP;

 END p_listar_cliente;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the declaration of variables. It must be before BEGIN.

```
PROCEDURE p_listar_cliente AS
clientes_cursor cliente%rowtype; -- moved it before BEGIN
 CURSOR clientes_cursor IS 
    SELECT id, name, address, salary FROM cliente;   -- moved it before BEGIN 

BEGIN
OPEN clientes_cursor;
LOOP
  FETCH clientes_cursor INTO clientes_cursor;
  EXIT WHEN clientes_cursor%notfound;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(clientes_cursor.id || ' ' || clientes.name);
 END LOOP;

 END p_listar_cliente;
```

Closing the cursor after using it is also good practice.

Cheers!!